# CloudKit rtfd reading

Tags: cloudkit, dashboard

My app reads and writes rtfd files to CloudKit using File Wrapper.
What I want to do is write the rtfd files using CloudKit Dashboard and read the files in my App.
When the Dashboard writes the files it adds a zip extention.
I have tried uncompressing the files.
Using FileWrapper.
I have even tried getting help from Apple support.
An example would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you saving the files to CloudKit? Are you saving them as `CKAsset` objects?

Comment: I currently write and read the rtfd files using CKasset and FileWrapper.  This works ok.  What I want to do is write the files using the Dashboard.  I cannot figure out how to read the rtfd files written using the Dashboard.

Comment: I can read the records but I can’t figure out how to convert the data retrieved in the asset back to a rtfd file that I can write to the Document folder in the App.

Comment: I can read rtf files written by the Dashboard.  When writing rtfd the Dashboard adds a zip extension.  Rtfd files are some kind of a multiple file file.